# as in your answers about 'Japanese' so far

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In a little survey, I have been asking queries about how the respondents feel about the word 'Japanese' as a noun. I now would like to ask them if the same answers that they've made apply to other nationality nouns with -ese, as far as they are concerned.

Do you think the phrase '**as in your answers so far**' works here, as normally 'the same' requires a parallel structure? Should it be "Do you feel the same way about the other nouns ... as you feel/do about 'Japanese' in your previous answers"?

> Do you feel the same way about the other nouns of nationality ending
>   in ese (examples: Portuguese, Chinese and Sudanese) **as in your answers
>   about 'Japanese' so far**?

Comment: Do you feel the same way about the other x as you do about your answers about Japanese? The auxiliary is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you compare feelings toward "other nouns of nationality" and "answers about Japanese", which are not quite the same thing.  This makes it a little hard to understand what you're asking.  Instead a nicely phrased parallel question would ask:

> Do you feel the same about X as you do Y?
>
> Would you answer the same about X as you would about Y?

This helps even more when you add in parenthetical phrases and other things that complicate a sentence.  I would write it differently:

> Would your answers be the same about other nationalities that end in -ese ("Chinese", etc.) as your answers so far about "Japanese"?
>
> Do you feel the same about other nouns of nationality that end in -ese ("Chinese", etc.) as you do about "Japanese"?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible construction:
"Would your answers remain the same if X was substituted for Y in the questions?" ie,
"Would your answers remain the same if another nationality ending in "ese" (such as Portuguese, Chinese, or Sudanese) was substituted for Japanese in the questions?"